# How to put a link on ADD Button?

Tags: html, button, addition

we need some help.
Do you know how to put a link on ADD Button?

```
  <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"> 
                <input type="submit" value="ADD PATIENT" name="ADD">
                 <input type="button" value="BACK" name="BACK">

            </td>
        </tr>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you give us more details and explain what isn't working? We don't understand what you mean by "put link on ADD button".

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by put a link on the button ?

Since your button has the type `submit`, it will send the content of your form to the url defined in its action property or the current url if none specified.

If you want to redirect the user to an url when he clicks on a button, first of all it shouldn't be a `submit` type and you will have to use some javascript.

A quick search on google ("html button link") provided the following tutorial for example : http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/buttons/article.php/3478871/So-You-Want-A-Link-Button-Huh.htm

I'm sur you can find more help by first searching on google if you want :) Just because I feel nice today, here's a quick example :

```
<input type="button" value="ADD PATIENT" name="ADD" onClick="parent.location='page.html'">
```

**Update**: The following will eventually work for you :

```
<a href="page.html"><button>ADD PATIENT</button></a>
```

But be aware that this doesn't **work in all browser**, but it doesn't require javascript.

You could also use a normal link that you can style like a button with CSS, a google search will provide you with plenty of links on how to do that ! (BTW, this is my preferred solution)

Comment: I would suggest the former method (using javascript) by @krtek

Answer (score 0):

I think this may also work for you

```
  <a href="page.html"><input type="button" value="ADD PATIENT" name="ADD"/></a>
```